# Problem in For loop

Tags: solidity

I'm learning to code in solidity. The following code is supposed to check whether a number in the 'tab' array is even or not. But the loop is not incrementing, it's stuck at 0

contract MyContract {

```
uint[] public tab = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function isEvenNumber(uint i) public view returns(bool) {

for(i=0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    return(tab[i] % 2 == 0);
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to check the number in the tab array is even or not?

isEvenNumber(3) -> true (cause tab[3] = 4)
isEvenNumber(4) -> false (cause tab[4] = 5)

If you want your function work that way,I think the code below would work.

```
function isEvenNumber(uint index) public view returns(bool) {
    return(tab[index] % 2 == 0);
}
```